# Font awesome fonts are not loading, showing squares in HTML

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome, webfonts

I've recently cloned the website from `HTTRACTs` but it seems to have a problem the icons like Facebook and Instagram on the entire pages is appearing like square and when I open in inspect element the error log says `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` but files are there and paths are proper also I've entered the code of

> @import url("https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

but that won't work either please help me out.

[Error messages which I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDByF.png)

Comment: Please edit your post to introduce punctuation (sentences), paragraphs, and other formatting for clarity. Put as much effort into your English as you do into your code. This includes the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original website does not use `CDN`, it uses a package of font-awesome.

Its ask for `.woff and .ttf` files, you can add it with the below solution.

download zip from `font-awesome` (free for web)

https://fontawesome.com/download

when you get the zip, extract it and now you get too many files, from that you need one folder `webfonts` and one file `all.min.css or all.css`.

now link `all.min.css or all.css` with your HTML file and put your folder to the exact previous location of you `all.min.css or all.css`, I will give a sample folder structure to know what I mean by this line.

**SAMPLE FOLDER STRUCTURE**

```
assets
   |-- css
   |    | -- all.min.css
   |-- webfonts
```

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!